# Logging in to headless Ubuntu Server has started take Long Time

Tags: login, headless, timeout

recently I've been having trouble with one of my (headless) Ubuntu servers. Critical software like NFS and munge have stopped working, and it seems to be because of how long it takes to log into the computer (about an minute an a half). Every similar issue I can find posts about online are specifically for ssh taking a long time, but this issue occurs for even if logging in to the computer physically. Because of this, I don't even know where to begin debugging or looking at things to fix. Any help, in terms of what logs or programs to look at, or what further information would be helpful, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can start with `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze blame`, also `journalctl --boot --lines=all --follow` should help too.

Comment: You start with what version of Ubuntu are you using? https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask a must read.

Comment: How do you log in to the headless server, what software are you using for this? Are you using Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: @Joe, @David, we are currently on `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`. To log in to the headless server, we either use `ssh` or nothing at all, using the terminal plugged directly into the computer. It takes a long time to log in in either case, so the problem doesn't seem related to ssh.